# Array of NSManagedObjectIDs, fetch the objects at once

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an array of NSManagedObjectID.  Is there a more efficient way to fetch the associated managed objects either than looping through the array and getting them individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perform a `fetchRequest` with the following predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@", arrayOfIds];
```

**Full example**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = myEntityDescription;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@", arrayOfIds];

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = mySortDescriptors;

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *managedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release]; fetchRequest = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't know you could use self as a managed object ID